# Getting String from StringBuilder

Tags: java, stringbuilder

I was working with `StringBuilder` to eliminate some unnecessary chars, I got some strange result.

```
String value = "1.045,00";
StringBuilder sanitized = new StringBuilder();
boolean decimalSeparatorFound = false;
char[] chars = value.toCharArray();
for (int i = chars.length-1; i >= 0; i--) {
    if (chars[i] == ',' || chars[i] == '.') {
        if (decimalSeparatorFound) continue;  // skip this char
        decimalSeparatorFound = true;
        sanitized.append('.');
    } else {
        sanitized.append(chars[i]);
    }
}
```

here I will get 00.5401 as a result in `sanitized` but when I was converting it to string like

```
String s = sanitized.reverse.toString();
```

and It is expected to print the value of `s` as `1045.00` but it get printed as `00.5401`.

then I tried it as

```
StringBuilder sb = sanitized.reverse();
String s1 = sb.toString();
```

now this time it got printed correctly.

here my question why the StringBuilder is behaving this way? Isn't it performing reverse operation while assigning the value to `String s`?

Comment: It's not the StringBuilder, it's this line: `for (int i = chars.length-1; i >= 0; i--) {`

Comment: Here is no use of reverse.

Comment: This is pretty unclear because `sanitized.reverse().toString()` should be identical with `sb = sanitized.reverse(); s=sb.toString()`. Did you miss something? Can you paste the 2 different codes?

Comment: Looking for that, pasting full code

Comment: Add this line after your for loop to see what's going on: `System.out.println(chars[i]);` then replace the for loop with this: `for (int i = 0; i < chars.length; i++) {` to fix it

Comment: @LynxZh yes your right, the problem was due to calling reverse method twice. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *"my question why the StringBuilder is behaving this way?"*

What's happening is that if you  have both ways in the same code, it will reverse once, then reverse again

```
StringBuilder sb = sanitized.reverse();     // first reverse
String s1 = sb.toString();

String s = sanitized.reverse().toString();  // second reverse

System.out.println(s1);
System.out.println(s);

OUTPUT

1045.00
00.5401
```

But if you take out the first reverse and just use the second reverse by itself, you get the correct output

```
String s = sanitized.reverse().toString();
System.out.println(s);

OUPUT

1045.00
```

Comment: yes, that was the reason. Actually I was reversing the string twice before printing it for the first time. so was getting it reversed.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't call reverse method in the right way.
You should call it `reverse()` with braces.

Your line should be like this:

```
// now they will give you the same results
String s1 = sanitized.reverse().toString();
System.out.println(s1) //1045.00

StringBuilder sb = sanitized.reverse();
String s1 = sb.toString();
System.out.println(s1) //1045.00
```

Answer (score 0):

Change append to insert

```
            sanitized.insert(0, '.');
        } else {
            sanitized.insert(0, chars[i]);
        }
```

I would do it simpler

```
    String decimalSeparator = s.indexOf(',') > s.indexOf('.') ? "." : ",";
    s = s.replace(decimalSeparator, "");
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing this

```
for (int i = chars.length-1; i >= 0; i--)
```

you should try this

```
for (int i = 0; i <chars.length; i++)
```

May be you are using reverse two times.

Answer (score 0):

In this loop, You are reversing the string by appending to StringBuilder from chars[chars.length-1] to chars[0]

```
for (int i = chars.length-1; i >= 0; i--) {
    if (chars[i] == ',' || chars[i] == '.') {
        if (decimalSeparatorFound) continue;  // skip this char
        decimalSeparatorFound = true;
        sanitized.append('.');
    } else {
        sanitized.append(chars[i]);
    }
}
```

This is the actual reason for the reversion. You should change the loop like this

```
for (int i = 0; i < chars.length; i++) {
        if (chars[i] == ',' || chars[i] == '.') {
            if (decimalSeparatorFound) continue;  // skip this char
            decimalSeparatorFound = true;
            sanitized.append('.');
        } else {
            sanitized.append(chars[i]);
        }
    }
```

So, it will work as you expect

Answer (score 0):

**Can you please try this:**

Use StringBuilder's or StringBuffer's method... reverse()

```
public class StringReverse
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
  String string=args[0];
  String reverse = new StringBuilder(string).reverse().toString();
  System.out.println("\nString before reverse: "+string);
  System.out.println("String after reverse: "+reverse);
  } 
}
```

StringBuffer is **thread-safe**, where as StringBuilder is **Not thread safe**.....

StringBuilder was introduced from Java 1.5, as to do those operations faster which doesn't have any Concurrency to worry about....

Hope this helps..